# Redirect wrongly mistyped URL to main domain

Tags: .htaccess

I need to Redirect my mistyped url into main domain ..

For example if user type **mistyped.domain.com** or **domain.com/mistyped** (which does not exists) .It should display the content of **domain.com** but the url in adress bar should be same as **mistyped.domain.com** or **domain.com/mistyped**

Note : I googled and tried some of the .htaccess but its just redirecting.
The url in the adressbar is not samejust **domain.com** not **mistyped.domain.com.**

Comment: This is not a good idea as google will see this as duplicated content. Just create a custom 404 page using the `ErrorDocument` command.

Comment: its not for google...ijust ned it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked

```
./mysite.com
    dirs and folders

./m.mysite.com
    drwxr-xr-x main_site -> ../mysite.com
```